# ¿No me funciona el OnClick en el RecyclerView Android?

Tags: android-studio, firebase, android-fragment, recyclerview, onclicklistener

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en Android Studio donde guardo información de poductos en firebase, mi problema es que estoy usando un recyclerview que me muestra productos de comida que estan en Firebase Realtime Database, al hacer click en un item me debe pasar los datos de ese item a unos editText, aunque por el momento solo quiero que me muestre un Toast con el Nombre del producto ,pero cuando oprimo el item no pasa nada.
Segui un tutorial para crear el OnClick con el Adapter para el RecyclerView, que ya antes en otro proyecto me había servido pero en esta ocasión no.

Adapter del RecylcerView:

```
public class AdapterDatos extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterDatos.ViewHolderDatos>
                        implements View.OnClickListener{

ArrayList<Producto> listDatos;
private View.OnClickListener listener;

public AdapterDatos(ArrayList<Producto> listDatos) {
    this.listDatos = listDatos;
}

//CONECTAR EL LAYOUT CON EL ADAPTER
@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolderDatos onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.item_producto_grid,null,false);

    view.setOnClickListener(this);

    return new ViewHolderDatos(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolderDatos holder, int position) {
    holder.nombre_list.setText(listDatos.get(position).getNombre());
    holder.tipo_list.setText(listDatos.get(position).getTipo());
    holder.valor_list.setText(listDatos.get(position).getValor());
    Glide
            .with(holder.imagen_list.getContext())
            .load(Producto.getImageUri())
            .into(holder.imagen_list);

}

//OBTENER EL TAMAÑO DE LA LISTA
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listDatos.size();
}

public void setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener listener){
    this.listener = listener;
}

@Override
public void onClick (View view){
    if (listener!=null){
        listener.onClick(view);
    }
}

public class ViewHolderDatos extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ImageView imagen_list;
    TextView nombre_list, tipo_list, valor_list;

    public ViewHolderDatos(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imagen_list = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imagen_producto_list);
        nombre_list = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.nombre_producto_list);
        tipo_list = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tipo_producto_list);
        valor_list = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.valor_producto_list);
    }
}
```

}

Este es el codigo del Fragment:

```
    public static CreateFragment newInstance() {
    return new CreateFragment();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                         @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.create_fragment, container, false);

    imagenProduct = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.p_Imagen);
    btnCrear = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.p_crear);
    btnImagen = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.p_galeria);
    btnLimpiar = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.p_cancelar);
    btnActualizar = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.p_actualizar);
    txvErrorImagen = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.p_errorImagen);
    txvErrorNombre = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.p_errorName);
    txvErrorDescrip = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.p_errorDescrip);
    txvErrorValor = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.p_errorValor);
    etNombre = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.p_Name);
    etDescrip = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.p_descrip);
    etValor = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.p_valor);
    spTipo = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner_producto);
    spList = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.sp_list);
    rcvList = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rcv_productos);

    //ADAPTER SPINNER
    String[] product = {"EMPANADA", "BEBIDA", "COMBO", "INSUMOS", "OTROS"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.spinner_item_tipo, product);
    spTipo.setAdapter(adapter);
    spList.setAdapter(adapter);

    btnActualizar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            listarDatos();
        }
    });

    btnLimpiar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ClearBox();
        }
    });

    btnImagen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            cargarImagen();
        }
    });

    btnCrear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Verificar();
        }
    });

    inicializarFirebase();
    construirRecycler();

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    mViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(CreateViewModel.class);
    // TODO: Use the ViewModel
}

//INICIAR FIREBASE
private void inicializarFirebase() {
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(getContext());
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    dataref = database.getReference();
    storageref = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

    Glide.with(getActivity())
            .load(R.drawable.imagen_splash)
            .fitCenter()
            .into(imagenProduct);
}

//LISTAR DATOS
private void listarDatos() {
    tipoList = spList.getSelectedItem().toString();
    dataref.child("Productos").child(tipoList).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            listProductos.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot objSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Producto p = objSnapshot.getValue(Producto.class);
                listProductos.add(p);

                AdapterDatos adapter = new AdapterDatos(listProductos);
                rcvList.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
}

//CREAR RECYCLERVIEW EN ESTA PARTE CREO QUE ESTA EL ERROR 
private void construirRecycler(){
    listProductos = new ArrayList<Producto>();
    //rcvList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(),LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false));
    rcvList.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2));

    listarDatos();

    AdapterDatos adapter = new AdapterDatos(listProductos);
    adapter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Nombre: "+listProductos
                    .get(rcvList.getChildAdapterPosition(view)).getTipo(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    rcvList.setAdapter(adapter);

}

//CARGAR IMAGEN DE GALERIA 
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
   if (resultCode==RESULT_OK){
        path= data.getData();
        Glide.with(getActivity())
                .load(path)
                .fitCenter()
                .into(imagenProduct);
        imagenProduct.setImageURI(path);
        txvErrorImagen.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        imagenB = true;
    }else{
       Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Imagen No Valida", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        txvErrorImagen.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        imagenB = false;
    }
}

//ABRIR GALERIA
private void cargarImagen() {
    Intent cargarInt= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    cargarInt.setType("image/");
    startActivityForResult(cargarInt.createChooser(cargarInt,"Seleccione la Aplicación"),10);
}

//ACCION BTN LIMPIAR CAMPOS DE DATOS
public void ClearBox() {
    etNombre.setText("");
    etDescrip.setText("");
    etValor.setText("");
    spTipo.setSelection(0);
    txvErrorImagen.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    txvErrorNombre.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    txvErrorDescrip.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    txvErrorValor.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    path = null;
    downloadUri = null;
    downloadURL = "";
    Glide.with(getActivity())
            .load(R.drawable.imagen_splash)
            .fitCenter()
            .into(imagenProduct);
}

//GUARDAR DATOS CON IMAGEN
private void crear() {
    Producto p = new Producto();
    p.setUid(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    p.setNombre(nombreP);
    p.setDescrip(descripP);
    p.setValor("$"+valorP);
    p.setTipo(spProducto);
    p.setImageUri(downloadURL);
    dataref.child("Productos").child(spProducto).child(p.getUid()).setValue(p);
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Producto Creado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

//IMAGEN A STORAGE
public void Storage() {
    final StorageReference filePath = storageref.child("Productos").child(path.getLastPathSegment());
    Task<Uri> uploadTask = filePath.putFile(path).continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
        @Override
        public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                throw task.getException();
            }
            return filePath.getDownloadUrl();
        }
    }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()){
                downloadUri = task.getResult();
                downloadURL = downloadUri.toString();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Imagen guardada", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                crear();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error al Subir la Imagen", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}

//ACCION VERIFICAR VALIDEZ CAMPOS
private void Verificar() {
    nombreP = etNombre.getText().toString();
    descripP = etDescrip.getText().toString();
    valorP = etValor.getText().toString();
    spProducto = spTipo.getSelectedItem().toString();
    int correcto = 0;

    if (nombreP.equals("")) {
        txvErrorNombre.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        txvErrorNombre.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        correcto++;
    }

    if (descripP.equals("")) {
        txvErrorDescrip.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        txvErrorDescrip.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        correcto++;
    }

    if (valorP.equals("")) {
        txvErrorValor.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        txvErrorValor.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        correcto++;
    }

    if (imagenProduct.getDrawable() != null ){
        txvErrorImagen.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        correcto++;
    }else{
        txvErrorImagen.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    if (imagenB = true) {
        txvErrorImagen.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        correcto++;
    }

    if (correcto == 5) {
        Storage();
        ClearBox();
    }
}
```

}

Este es el codigo del xml, el recyclerview esta al final y es el ultimo elemento que coloque :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context=".ui.createProduct.CreateFragment">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/p_LinearL"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="4dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/p_Titulo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/bevan"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|top"
            android:text="@string/titulo_productos"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/p_LinearL_Botones"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/p_crear"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/b_circular_amarillo"
                android:contentDescription="@string/crear_productos"
                android:tint="@color/black"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_save_24" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/p_galeria"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/b_circular_amarillo"
                android:contentDescription="@string/galeria_productos"
                android:tint="@color/black"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu_camera" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/p_cancelar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/b_circular_amarillo"
                android:contentDescription="@string/limpiar_productos"
                android:tint="@color/black"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_cerrar" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/p_errorImagen"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/errorImagen_productos"
            android:textColor="@color/colorRojoError"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/p_Imagen"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_gravity="clip_horizontal|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/descripImagen_productos" 
         />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/p_separador"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/imagen"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@android:drawable/divider_horizontal_bright" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/p_errorName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/errorNombre_productos"
            android:textColor="@color/colorRojoError"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/p_inputName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/p_Name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/nombre_productos"
                android:importantForAutofill="no"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/p_errorDescrip"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/errorDescrip_productos"
            android:textColor="@color/colorRojoError"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/p_inputDescrip"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/p_descrip"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:gravity="start|top"
                android:hint="@string/description_productos"
                android:importantForAutofill="no"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/p_errorValor"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/errorValor_productos"
            android:textColor="@color/colorRojoError"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner_producto"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/p_inputValor"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/p_valor"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:gravity="start|top"
                    android:hint="@string/valor_productos"
                    android:importantForAutofill="no"
                    android:inputType="text|number" />

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/p_lista"
                    android:layout_width="340dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/bevan"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal|top"
                    android:text="@string/lista_productos"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="26sp" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/p_actualizar"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                    
  android:contentDescription="@string/actualizar_productos"
                    android:tint="@color/white"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_reload" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/sp_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:foregroundGravity="center" />

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rcv_productos"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

En tu metodo `construirRecyclerview` estas haciendo `setOnClickListener` pero del objeto, lo que deberias hacer ahi simplemente es pasar el listener que seria el fragmento

```
AdapterDatos adapter = new AdapterDatos(listProductos);
adapter.setOnClickListener(this)
```

Luego te va a pedir que implementes la interfaz OnClickListener en tu fragment

```
CreateFragment implements View.OnClickListener ...
```

y luego usas tu `onClick` en el fragment

```
@Override
public void onClick (View view){ ... }
```